# Trying to write a code to remove properties in Powerpoint file

Tags: excel, powershell, powerpoint

***Hello,
I am trying to create a PowerShell script where it takes the properties of a PowerPoint file and removes them so they no issues are being caused by it but with the code I am making I am trying to copy some code that does the same thing excel and word and just change something over to PowerPoint and it doesn't seem to want to work***

***Code that I've tried so far (forgive me I'm not the most experienced with PowerShell)***

```
$path = “c:\fso”
Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint
$PpRemoveDocType = “Microsoft.Office.Interop.Powerpoint.PpRemoveDocInfoType” -as [type]
$pointFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -include *.pot, *.ppt, *.pps -recurse
$objPoint.visible = $false
$objPoint = New-Object -ComObject powerpoint.application
foreach($wb in $pointFiles)
{
$workbook = $objPoint.workbooks.open($wb.fullname)
“Removing document information from $wb”
$workbook.RemoveDocumentInformation($PpRemoveDocType::xlRDIAll)
$workbook.Save()
$objPoint.Workbooks.close()
}
$objPoint.Quit()
```

***This is the Excel code for reference and it works just fine***

```
$path = “c:\fso”
Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
$xlRemoveDocType = “Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlRemoveDocInfoType” -as [type]
$excelFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -include *.xls, *.xlsx -recurse
$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application
$objExcel.visible = $false
foreach($wb in $excelFiles)
{
$workbook = $objExcel.workbooks.open($wb.fullname)
“Removing document information from $wb”
$workbook.RemoveDocumentInformation($xlRemoveDocType::xlRDIAll)
$workbook.Save()
$objExcel.Workbooks.close()
}
$objExcel.Quit()
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Guessing that a powerpoint doc doesn't have a "workbooks" property.  Have you looked at the $objPoint object?  Also, posting the errors you are getting will help a lot.

Comment: Removed `C#` tag as it doesn't seem relevant in this question.

Comment: @MikeShepard is correct; there's no Workbooks object in PowerPoint. Instead, use Presentations

Answer (score 1):

This has worked for me in the past:

```
function handlePowerpointFiles ($file) {
    Write-Host "Processing file: " $file.Fullname
    Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.Office.Interop.Powerpoint
    $PpRemoveDocType = "Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpRemoveDocInfoType" -as [type]
    $objpp = New-Object -ComObject Powerpoint.Application
    $doc = $objpp.Presentations.Open($file.FullName, $false, $null, $false)
    $doc.RemoveDocumentInformation($PpRemoveDocType::ppRDIAll)
    $doc.Save()
    $doc.Close()
    $objpp.Quit()
}
```

The reason I wrapped it into a function, is because I wrote a small tool to handle all major Microsoft Office files, also perform some pre-checks if the file is locked or password protected. Essentially something along the lines of (simplified):

```
$path = "C:\Documents"
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -include *.doc, *.docx, *.xls, *.xlsx, *.ppt, *.pptx -Recurse
foreach ($fileEntry in $files) {
    if (CheckForFileLock $fileEntry.FullName) {
        Write-Error "File '$($fileEntry.FullName)' is locked" -ErrorAction Stop
    }
    if (CheckForPasswordProtection($fileEntry) -eq $true){
        Write-Error "File '$($fileEntry.FullName)' is password protected" -ErrorAction Stop
    } 
    Switch ($fileEntry.Extension){
        {$_ -in ".xls",".xlsx"} {
            handleExcelFiles $fileEntry
        }
        {$_ -in ".doc",".docx"} {
            handleWordFiles $fileEntry
        }
        {$_ -in ".ppt",".pptx"} {
            handlePowerpointFiles $fileEntry
        }
    }
}
```

You get the idea.